# Having trouble searching array

Tags: java

So I have everything working fine up until the point in which I need to search. I'm really new to this so my code is probably awful I'm sorry in advance. Anyway, its a user input array, and the user should be able to search for a number in an array. Im getting the error for a duplicate variable on line 50 (int i, get 1).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SearchingSorting {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println ("How many numbers would you like to input?");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        double[] array = new double[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.println ("Input number " + (1 + i) + ":");
            array[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        for (double temp1 : array){
            System.out.print (temp1 + "\t");
        }

        input.close();
        
        int pass;
        int i;
        int hold;
        
        for(pass = 1; pass < array.length; pass++)
            
        {
            
        for(i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
            
        {
                if(array[i] > array[i+1])
                    
                {
                    hold = (int) array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    array[i+1] = hold;
                }
        }
    
        
        System.out.println("\nSorted number is: ");
 
        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        
        }
        
        int i, get1;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[10];

      for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
          
        {
        numbers[i] = i * 10;
        
        }
      
     System.out.print("Enter search number: ");
      get1 = keyboard.nextInt();
      SearchMethod(numbers, get1);
      
        }
    
    
    public static void SearchMethod(int[] num, int get2)
    {
        
        int i ;
        boolean j = false;
        for(i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
            
            {
            if(num[i] == get2)
                
            {
                j = true;
                break;
            }
    }
        if(j == true)
                 System.out.println(get2 + " is found at num[" + i + "]");
        else
               System.out.println(get2 + " is not found in an array");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you search for a Integer type value within a double type array? Change `double[] array = new double[num];` to `int[] array = new int[num];`.

Comment: The values the user/my professor puts in wont be integers

Comment: you are trying to initialise again i in line 50 , while the original i is still there and its scope is not over.

Comment: Yes thank you. Im really new to this, its like out second project. Ive been looking at it for hours and have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Would you please mark line 50, somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare a new variable with the same name ("i") in the same scope.

Rename your variable i on line 50.